# Absolute path regex in jest.config.js

Tags: javascript, regex, jestjs

I would like to match absolute paths with regex in my `jest.config.js` same way as it is done in `jsconfig.json`.

```
 // jest.config.js
 {
   ...
   moduleNameMapper: {
     '^\+\/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/styles/'
     '^\~\/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/'
  },
 }
```

`'^\+\/(.*)$'` should match `+/theme/theme` and find file located in `Project/src/styles/theme/theme`

`'^\~\/(.*)$'` should match `'~/components/Account'` and find file located in `Project/src/components/Account`

Regex work: https://regex101.com/r/yXpeAu/1, https://regex101.com/r/jH6ajA/1

Unfortunately something is wrong because I got 2 errors during test run.

- `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^+/(.*)$/: Nothing to repeat`
- `Cannot find module './src/components/Account' from 'src/components/Account`

This is how jsconfig.json resolve absolute paths:

```
// jsconfig.json
{
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "paths": {
  "+/*": ["./src/styles/*"],
  "~/*": ["./src/*"],
  }
}
```

Comment: In JS regular string literals, backslashes must be doubled. `'^\+\/(.*)$'` => `'^\\+/(.*)$'` and `'^\~\/(.*)$'` => `'^~/(.*)$'` (`~` is not any special regex metacharacter).

Comment: Thanks, that seems better. Hmm but something still is wrong. Now I have `Cannot find module './src/styles/theme/theme' from 'src/components/Account.test.js`. It looks like it is trying to import file form local path, not absolute.